# Joining a domain from a remote location

Tags: active-directory, windows-server

I have a domain in site X and want to join a laptop from site Y to X's DC's domain. How can one do it? I've a PPTT VPN but I can't join it. I'm new to this, but not a complete noobie. I've been able to setup the DHCP, DNS, VPN, AD, some GPO here and there.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey @nori, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

•   You will need to check whether the DC site, i.e., site X’s DNS or AD server is reachable from site Y, i.e., from the client laptop. For that purpose, try pinging the DC by its FQDN and enter the DC server’s IP address in site X in the client laptop’s preferred DNS and the other replicating ADC (Additional Domain Controller) to the original DC in alternate DNS server space in the client laptop. Once done, please check the below list of ports whether they are reachable from the client laptop to the DC in site X and vice versa by using the telnet utility through command prompt or the powershell.

**List of ports**: -

```
         TCP and UDP 135 RPC Endpoint Mapper
         TCP and UDP 389 LDAP
         TCP 636 LDAP SSL
         TCP and UDP 464 Kerberos Password Change
         TCP and UDP 88 Kerberos
         TCP and UDP 137 NetBIOS Name Service
         UDP 138 NetBIOS Datagram Service
         TCP 139 NetBIOS Session Service
         TCP and UDP 445 SMB
         TCP 3268 Global catalog LDAP
         TCP 3269 Global catalog LDAP SSL
         TCP and UDP 53 DNS
         TCP and UDP 1512 WINS Resolution
         TCP and UDP 42 WINS Replication
         TCP 49152-65535 RPC Dynamic Ports
```

•   The above list of ports is required for smooth and relevant client to server and server to client communication to happen. You will need to whitelist these ports over the firewall in the VPN connection setup between the two sites. Also, ensure to enter the default gateway IP address set for the virtual network in which the client laptop resides.

•   Please ensure that the above-mentioned ports and their relevant services are running and available during the domain join operation on the DC in site X and the client laptop in site Y, thus ensuring smooth communication between the two. Once the above things are done, the laptop system should be able to join the domain. Also, ensure the Windows Firewall on the client laptop is configured to bypass the above stated ports and services and the network discovery is enabled on the client laptop.

Comment: My DNS does not work if I use its public ip, that seems to be the issue idk how to fix it though

Comment: Please check whether conditional forwarding is configured and enabled in your internal DNS so that on whichever public DNS server on the internet your custom domain is hosted, it will be reachable. And since, custom DNS hosting on a public server itself ensures that your domain name has a public IP, its various DNS records published on it will also have a public IP.